# Como colocar array de imagens em div separados?

Tags: javascript

Comecei o guia MDN e criei uma galeria de imagem no Codepen - [Galeria de imagens](https://codepen.io/ilson-ricardo/pen/YzeYGxW), seguindo o tutorial MDN - [Javascript construindo blocos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Image_gallery).

Depois de criar a galeria de imagens, me senti na necessidade de acrescentar alguns estilos para as imagens da galeria, como colocar as imagens em um circulo. Adicionei border-radius: 50%; e a imagem ficou com oval e não circulo.

Quero colocar cada imagem em uma div para configura o css direto ao div, como faço isso?
Segue o código abaixo:

```
const displayedImage = document.querySelector('.displayed-img');
const thumbBar = document.querySelector('.thumb-bar');
const images = [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic1.jpg`, 
                `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic2.jpg`, 
                `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic3.jpg`, 
                `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic4.jpg`, 
                `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic5.jpg`];

for (const image of images) {
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', `${image}`);
  thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);
  newImage.addEventListener('click', e => displayedImage.src = e.target.src);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Respondendo primeiramente sua dúvida de como inserir as imagens dentro de uma div, segue abaixo como fiz:

```
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('thumb');
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', `${image}`);
  newImage.addEventListener('click', e => displayedImage.src = e.target.src);
  newDiv.appendChild(newImage);
  thumbBar.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Eu testei aqui e ficou redondinho as fotos, vou postar o código completo, mas depois você coloca o estilo como você achar melhor, segue o CSS e JS:

CSS:

```
    img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
button {
 border: 0;
 background: rgba(150,150,150,0.6);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
}
.thumb-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 50px;
  
}

.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-bar img {
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

JS:

```
    const displayedImage = document.querySelector('.displayed-img');
    const thumbBar = document.querySelector('.thumb-bar');
    const images = [
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic1.jpg`,
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic2.jpg`,
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic3.jpg`,
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic4.jpg`,
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/risoweb/risoweb.github.io/master/pic5.jpg`
    ];

  for (const image of images) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('thumb');
    const newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.setAttribute('src', `${image}`);
    newImage.addEventListener('click', e => displayedImage.src = e.target.src);
    newDiv.appendChild(newImage);
    thumbBar.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
```

Comment: Olá, gostaria de saber se você criou um novo elemento para const newDiv e anexou o div?

Comment: Quando eu crio a variável newDiv eu já uso o método createElement, depois eu usso o classList.add para adicionar a classe 'thumb' nessa div criada. Depois eu crio o elemento da imagem e uso método appendChild na div para inserir a imagem dentro do elemento div, assim para cada div você vai ter uma imagem. Era isso sua dúvida?

Comment: Entendi que você criou uma variável e usou um método, até ai tudo beleza. Não consigo ver  o elemento div que está usando o método appendChild para interagir com o css e arredondar o circulo que esta oval. Gostaria de colocar os div arredondados, como círculos mesmo e mover a imagem para cima ou para baixo conforme a necessidade. Você pode acompanhar no Codepen como está o css, pois acredito que o css faz toda a diferença no estilo deste estudo. https://codepen.io/ilson-ricardo/pen/YzeYGxW?editors=0100

Comment: E o pior que ainda vou flutuar esse div para cima da imagem principal, como estão o botão cinza no alto. Por isso preciso entender perfeitamente esse css, estou faz algumas semanas com o pensamento nesse estudo e já consumi todo energia mental para absorver o JavaScript, espero que depois disso tudo sobre um pouco de energia para estudar os Objetos JavaScript ;)